# Cannot upload file in Laravel & Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Last week, I was able to upload the file (video in mp4 format) to a server, but today it couldn't be saved because of an error like "The media path failed to upload". If I upload any images, it worked instead of the videos.

Code:

```
    public function store(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'media_path' => "required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,mp4|max:3024",
        'video_thumbnail' => "nullable|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:3024",
        "title" => "nullable|string",
        "description" => "nullable|string",
        "published" => "nullable|boolean",
        "format" => "required|string",
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('media_path')) {
        $media_path = $request->media_path->storePublicly("sliders/images", ["disk" => "public"]);
    }

    $video_thumbnail = null;
    if ($request->hasFile('video_thumbnail')) {
        $video_thumbnail = $request->video_thumbnail->storePublicly("sliders/thumbnail", ["disk" => "public"]);
    }

    $slider->update([
        'media_path' => $media_path,
        "title" => $request->title,
        "description" => $request->description,
        "published" => $request->published,
        "format" => $request->format,
        "video_thumbnail" => $video_thumbnail,
    ]);

    return redirect("/admin/sliders")->banner("Sliders saved successfully");
}
```

I edit php.ini to increase the upload file size and then restart Apache but to no avail;

```
php_value memory_limit 30M
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

Where do I need to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what file size is the video?

Comment: the file size is 2.4mb

Comment: also, post your controller method code in which you're handling the upload.

Comment: Okay sure. Let me edit the post now.

Comment: please the method added

Comment: the code looks okay to me. can you try to upload a different video file and possibly which is in smaller size and tell me waht error you get

Comment: Okay sure give me a minute.

Comment: Hi, the error - media_path failed to upload. and validation error: media_path
: 
"media path failed to upload." when tried to upload video in webm and avi formats

Comment: If I remove the validation of the media path, a error i got is like this Symfony
 \ 
Component
 \ 
Mime
 \ 
Exception
 \ 
InvalidArgumentException
PHP 8.2.4
9.48.0
The "" file does not exist or is not readable. But in fact, the file really exists in the request

Comment: are you sure the file is valid? I mean are you sure if the fontend framework/library you're using to upload is sending a valid file ?

Comment: Yes I am very sure. I used @inertiajs/inertia-vue3 to upload video. I think I should try axios and see.

Comment: Just tried axios and get this error - "The sliders.0.media_path must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png, mp4."

Comment: I checked that the video cannot be sent to the server. Any idea why?

Comment: check permission for create file or folder may be 0775 for chmod

Comment: The issue was caused by a custom middleware I added recently. Thanks for using your time to help.

Comment: @LeslieJoe you can answer your own question with above answer (if you want)